# Google sheets: How to dynamically change the color of bar chart based on cell value with google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

I made a gantt chart on excel (see screenshot), and I'm trying to figure out how to dynamically change the color of a bar based on assignee (team member). For reference, this is nothing but a stacked bar chart, where the first part of the column is just made to be transparent. There are 2 series: "Start on day" - transparent, and "Duration" - light blue.

[image]

As you can see right now, all bars are the same color, while I want something like this:

[image]

So I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51030982/change-bar-color-based-on-cell-value) piece of code, I edited it a little bit, and managed to make it work so that when I change a name in the Team member column, it colors the chart differently (essentially it receives a CSS color code from a hidden column). Problem is, it colors all the bars (because it's targeting a series) and not just one. I couldn't find a way to make it work with one bar only.

Suggestions? Any help is much appreciated. (code below)

```js
function modifyChart_(sheet, newCssColor) {
  // Assume there is only one chart on this sheet.
  const charts = sheet.getCharts();
  const barBuilder = charts[0].modify().asBarChart();
  const option = {};

  option[0] = {"color": "rgba(255,255,255, 0"};
  option[1] = {};
  option[2] = {"color": newCssColor};
  barBuilder.setOption("series", option);

  // Update the chart on the sheet.
  sheet.updateChart(barBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### How to set the colors of a bar chart statically

Sample:

```
function modifyChart(sheet, newCssColor) {
  // Assume there is only one chart on this sheet.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  const charts = sheet.getCharts();
  const barBuilder = charts[0].modify().asBarChart().setColors(["red", "green", "grey"]);
   sheet.updateChart(barBuilder.build());
}
```

> Note:
>
> - Apps Script considers functions whose name ends in an underscore `_` private — such function can be called from other functions, but you cannot run them directly in the script editor
> - The most convenient method for changing bar colors is [setColors](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/bar-chart-builder#setcolorscssvalues)

### How to set the color of a bar chart dynamically from a cell value

Sample:

```
function modifyChart(sheet, newCssColor) {
  // Assume there is only one chart on this sheet.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  const charts = sheet.getCharts();
  var array = [];
  //assuming the color values are in cells A10, A11 and A12
  var colorValues = sheet.getRange("A10:A12").getValues();
  for(var i = 0; i < colorValues.length; i++){
    array.push(colorValues[i][0]);
  }
  const barBuilder = charts[0].modify().asBarChart().setColors(array);
  sheet.updateChart(barBuilder.build());
}
```

> References:
>
> - [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
> - [array.push()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)

Comment: This seems to fit my case, I'll test this evening. One question tho: is there a way to make the range dynamic? Such as, I add a new task, that is a new row, so color range would now be from row 10 to 13. What if I make a data table and reference the length of it?

Comment: By adding a new task you mean adding a new column to the chart? You can use [getDataRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange) to dynamically access the length of the range (in this case it is convenient if your color table is in a separate sheet from the chart). Also, you can assign with `setColors` more colors than there are columns in the chart. The number of values from the array what will be used by the chartbuilder corresponds to the number of columns, the rest of the values will be ignored until you add more columns.

Comment: no i meant a new row, like a new task for the gantt chart, so an additional line.
I managed to make your script work but for some reason it still colors all the bars instead of just one. I'm suspecting it's referencing the data column?

Comment: so, according to the comments on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56776618/set-separate-colors-for-each-bar-with-app-script-columchart-builder) thread, it seems that both setColor and setOptions work on series only, to color a single element differently I probably will need to make some kind of pivot table.

Comment: If what you want to do is color each element differently, this is a different question. For this you need methods from the [Google Chart API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#overview).

Comment: yeah that was the idea, I'm sorry it wasn't clear to begin with. I resorted to making a pivot table of the original data, essentially transposing it and grouping by team member. So the series become rows and are inverted, now each task is a different series. This way I can color them differently, I bet.

Comment: So, my last solution apparently doesn't work, because when you invert rows and columns in the graph it also changes the way it looks at series, so it seems to be actually impossible to programmatically color single elements in a bar chart :(

Comment: I recommend you to sue the methods of the google Chart API to [color bars](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#coloring-bars).

Comment: Ye I guess that's my only option, but can they be embedded in google sheets?