# How to modify google sheet chart color based on cell value using app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts, google-visualization

I want to create a dynamic chart that changes the color based on a cell value. I used the example in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60845511) but it only uses the first color I declared in the legend as seen in this image:

[image]

```
function modifyChart(sheet, newCssColor) {
  // Assume there is only one chart on this sheet.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  const charts = sheet.getCharts();
  var array = [];

  var colorValues = sheet.getRange("G4:G6").getValues();
  for(var i = 0; i < colorValues.length; i++){
    array.push(colorValues[i][0]);
  }

Logger.log(colorValues);
  const barBuilder = charts[0].modify().asColumnChart().setColors(array);
  sheet.updateChart(barBuilder.build());
}
```

But here's exactly want to do:

```
If score <= 49 set bar color to red
Else if score >= 50 and score <= 89 set bar color to orange
else set bar color to green
```

Just like how the cell background changes because I set rules to it using Conditional Formatting.

**Edit**: Change the the cell range to match the sample

Comment: Do you mean in a similar way to the UI's `Customise > Series`, `Add` under 'Format data point`? Maybe recording a macro would help see how the individual lines can have their colour changed?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo, yes that's the same in context. Although when you use format data point, you can only set static colour. I want it to be dynamically assigned based on cell value.

Comment: in the code posted, the colors are retrieved from column `I` -- `I3:I6` -- but in the picture, it shows the color legend values are in column `G` -- `G4:G6` -- what is in column `I`?

Comment: @WhiteHat, I copied the result in another sheet that is why the column does not match on what's in the code. I cannot show the real data here.

Answer (score 2):

Each of your categories is a series in your embedded chart.
You want to set the style options of each series individually.
Use [`setOption()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder#setoptionoption,-value) and set the color options for each series.

#### For example:

`EmbeddedChartBuilder.setOption('series.0.color', 'red').setOption('series.1.color', 'orange').setOption('series.2.color', 'green').build()`